# computation of multiple logical operators "or" ,"and" in one statement

Tags: python, output, logical-operators

```py
print(6 and 0 or 5==9 and 4 and '7' or 0 and 8)
print(4 or 8 and 56==0 or 5 and 0 or 5 and 'hoe' or 0 and 'f')
```

what is the order of computation of **multiple logical operators** in python?
is it sequentially from either side?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows the precedence order as defined in [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

In short, NOT > AND > OR.

Your code translates to:

```
(6 and 0) or (5==9 and 4 and '7') or (0 and 8)
(4) or (8 and 56==0) or (5 and 0) or (5 and 'hoe') or (0 and 'f')
```